# Okta-MFA on mobile app using okta/react-native

Tags: react-native, okta, multi-factor-authentication

We are not able to get MFA working with the okta/react-native package for our mobile app. Has anyone tried / succeeded in integrating MFA based authentication with Okta as the Identity Management platform on mobile side?
Any pointers of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!